# Incorrect variable arguments R

Tags: r, web-scraping

Sorry for my bad english. Here I use R langage.

I want to get the first 5 URLs of a website, but the variable's arguments **nb_pages** doesn't want return request information. For your information, I'm using here is RStudio as code editor.

Below the code concerned, I want to specify that this is a recovery of a code in open-source, and to practice R I try to understand it by correcting the errors encountered, but there I'm lock. Some **library** that you will see aren't necessary for execution of this code, it's in premise of the continuation when I would have passed this error :

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(photon)
 
go_GET <- function(url){
  result=GET(url,
             add_headers(
               "User-Agent" = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:62.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/62.0",
               "Accept"="text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
               "Accept-Language"="fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3"))
  return(result)
}
go_GET("https://www.leboncoin.fr/ventes_immobilieres/offres/rhone_alpes/rhone/")
 
url_base <- "https://www.leboncoin.fr/ventes_immobilieres/offres/rhone_alpes/rhone/"
url_base_raw <- go_GET(url_base)
html_base <- read_html(url_base_raw)
 
nb_links <- html_base  %>% 
  html_nodes("._2ilNG") %>%
  html_text() %>% 
  first() %>% 
  str_replace(" ","") %>% 
  as.numeric()
nb_pages=ceiling(nb_links/35)
 
 
pages=c(url_base,
        str_c(url_base,"p-",2:nb_pages))
pages[1:5]
```

Below is the answer from console :

```
> ...
> pages=c(url_base,
+         str_c(url_base,"p-",2:nb_pages))
Error in 2:nb_pages : NA/NaN argument
> pages[1:5]
[1] "https://www.leboncoin.fr/ventes_immobilieres/offres/rhone_alpes/rhone/"
[2] NA                                                                      
[3] NA                                                                      
[4] NA                                                                      
[5] NA 
>
```

Best regards,

Comment: I'm getting `HTTP error 403`. Or `Forbidden (HTTP 403).`

Comment: You use exactly same "User-Agent" like me ? Maybe your "User-Agent" is various. Or if you try to read a page in Leboncoin using the read_html() function directly you’ll likely get a 403 error message.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code. And that's what I got yesterday. If I use the browser, I get a not-a-robot verification.

Comment: Package httr, rvest, tidyverse and knitr are correctly download and install before attaching it to environment with library() ?

Comment: Yes, they are. And though package knitr is not used in the call to `go_GET` it is installed and attached with `library`.